# Angular - Change state without reloading the page (ui-router 1.0)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes, angular-ui-router

Before ui-router 1.0 I could use **notify: false** when redirecting from state A to state B without page reload.

```
$state.go('C', {
            param1: param1Data
        }, {
            notify: false
        });
```

Now notify has been replaced by dynamic parameters. It works when redirecting to the same state or a child state.

My case is as follows:
- State A redirects to state C.
- State B redirects to state C.

Here is a short version of my routes:

```
        {
            name: `A`,
            url: '/:create/',
            template: `flights.html`,
            controller: FlightController,
            controllerAs: '$ctrl',
            resolve: {
                booking: ['$transition$', ($transition$ : Transition) => {
                    ...
                }]
            }
        },

        {
            name: `B`,
            url: '/:copy/',
            template: `flights.html`,
            controller: FlightController,
            controllerAs: '$ctrl',
            resolve: {
                booking: ['$transition$', ($transition$ : Transition) => {
                ...
                }]
            }
        },


        {
            name: `C`,
            url: '/:delete/',
            template: `flights.html`,
            controller: FlightController,
            controllerAs: '$ctrl',
            params: {
                booking: { dynamic: true, value: null }
            }
        }
```

I guess I could create two child states, A.C and B.C. But I want to avoid code duplication.

When located in state A, I cannot enter state C with dynamic parameter without reloading the page:

```
    // From A
    $state.go('C', {
        param1: param1Data
    };
```

So the question is, have you any idea how I can change states without reloading the page using ui-router 1.0?

Comment: Do you want to change state or URL only without reloading controller?

Comment: I want to change the state and the URL also. There is a typo in my routes examples above. The url should be '/delete/' not '/:delete/.